# TimeoutError: transforming ..\node_modules\aws-sdk\dist\aws-sdk-react-native.js

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk

I've been having an error when trying to run/test my react-native application on my mobile device. The error seems to be originating from aws-sdk as below:

[image]

Is anyone familiar with this error and knows how to fix it?

- react-native: 0.45.1
- aws-sdk: 2.223.1

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1748#issuecomment-392040722

After much attempts with the latest release i was able to get v2.224.1 working. I use react native v0.44.1.